# Angular frontend authentication when using Grails and Spring Security for backend

Tags: angularjs, grails, spring-security

I'm writing an Angular app which has Grails with Spring Security as a backend. I don't want to couple frontend with backend, so I don't use any `gsp`'s, the communication goes only through REST requests.

Now the question comes which authentication to use.

Form authentication could be useful, but spring security redirects to the default form page and my login page is outside of Grails (in Angular project). I don't need a form page from spring security, I just need a URL where I can do my post request with credentials and get a cookie back.

So I started with `Basic authentication` which is easy enough, but then we have to add `Authorization` header to each request, which is annoying and not secure.

Spring security allows `remember me` cookie, but it is coupled to form authentication, so it is not possible (or difficult) to use it with basic authentication.

Stateless token authentication (for example, JWT) sounds great, but it is not clear how to configure it with Grails. The documentation for Security plugin has no mention about stateless authentication: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/index.html

So what is the best way to do authentication from Angular in Spring Secirity?

Comment: use  https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest

Comment: yes, I saw the plugin, but I already use `Grails Spring Security` plugin, which allows nice stuff. So I wonder if it's possible using security plugin instead.

Comment: well `spring-security-rest` is an extension for the rest authentication but it is based on spring-security-core so its still needed so you still use that for the other features

Comment: I've used `spring-security-rest`. In short: it works!

Comment: guys, can I use `spring security plugin` und `spring security rest` at the same time or do I have to choose?

Comment: make sure to check the plugin doc http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/ it says to add both dependencies with an exclude

Answer (score 0):

You are using default behavior of spring security. If you want stateless authentication, you will have to override the default behavior. Please go through [this wiki page](https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-grails-sample/wiki/3-basic-auth) and also see [this sample app](https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-grails-sample) for angular backend.